# Lua library for data analysis (data frames)

Tags: lua, dataframe, data-analysis, torch

Is there any Lua implementation of data frames - structures for data analysis which? Something like Python pandas. I want to do some statistical operations using LuaJIT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is now. Check out [torch-dataframe](https://github.com/AlexMili/torch-dataframe) that I and Alex are developing. Our main priority is reliability that we check with a rich test suite. Performance comes second although we try to avoid performance hogs within the limits of Lua.

The package is currently far from the pandas sophistication, but feel free to contribute with any methods you feel lacking.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Torch7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torch_%28machine_learning%29) that provides N-dimensional arrays with support for various statistical and mathematical operations and is based on LuaJIT.

Comment: I know Torch7, but I can't find there the functionality of data frames.

Comment: there isn't an explicit package for data-frames. using the csv package (csvigo) along with regular lua tables is your best option right now.